# Is this correct to use "tell" in this following word?

Tags: verbs

> "Please tell Mr. Anderson to turn on his system"

Is this is the right sentence to request our senior person to let other person to turn on that person's system?

Please mention what is the difference between ask and tell?

Comment: Asking someone to do something is an explicit request. Telling someone to do something is generally a command.

Comment: seems correct to me

Comment: @jimsug: So I need to put 'ask' instead of tell when I requesting them. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the language of English quite polite. Normally, we request others to do something! :)

Generally, we use *tell* when we want to explicitly ***instruct*** someone/something. On the other hand, we use *ask* when we ***request.***

For example...

> Will you ***tell*** your kid to stop running around? 
>   Will you ***ask*** your husband to look into the matter and help me?

This said, if you are instructing someone, use *...tell Mr. Anderson...* and if you are requesting, use *...ask....*.

[Just a note: In your case, there are ***two*** requests (as you said). The first request is yours to your senior and the second, your senior requesting Mr. Anderson].

Good read on [BBC is here.](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv256.shtml) This will help you understanding the nuance of those words.

Comment: I think both are requests - it is a request (to an unknown third party) to either request that, or command, Mr Anderson to turn on his system. The appropriateness of either will depend on this third person's relationship with Mr Anderson, not the speaker's.